# Use \let with \csname

Tags: tex-core, csname

My basic question (I think) is: How do I use `\let` together with `\csname ... \endcsname`. So basically I'm trying to get this to work:

```
\newcommand{\setcolwidth}[2]{
    \expandafter\newlength\csname col#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\let\csname col#1\endcsname\dimexpr#2
}
```

## The background

I created a grid layout. This works similar to a table with a lot more functions. The basic idea can be taken from my example (at the bottom).

**My problem**

As you can see in the image, my grid layout is not correct. The columns are too long.

[image]

**What I think is happening**

I am setting the widths of my columns. This does something like `\@namedef{col1}{.5\textwidth}`.

I'm not very familar with how TeX is working but I think it this is "expanding" the command. Im my imagination this means replacing the `\@nameuse{col1}` with `.5\textwidth`.

I am using the `\@nameuse{...}` inside a `minipage` environment. This means that the `\textwidth` will be changed. So when TeX is simply replacing my own command by the `\textwidth` this will use the `\textwidth` of the `minipage`. But I want to have the `\textwidth` outside of the `minipage`.

**My solution**

I was looking around in the web to find a solution. If I got everything correct, the `\let` command will save the real value of the width because it is executing the argument. So I was trying to use `\@namelet` but I did not find out how it is working. There are nearly no examples on google or on stackexchange.

The next thing I found is the `\csname ... \endcsname` so now I'm trying to use this. But I don't know how those commands are working or why my example is not working.

**Example code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
% \setcolwidth{column number}{width}
\newcommand{\setcolwidth}[2]{
    \@namedef{col#1}{#2}
}
% \colwidth{column number} -> width of column
\newcommand{\colwidth}[1]{
    \dimexpr\@nameuse{col#1}
}
\makeatother

% separator
\newlength{\colsep}
\setlength{\colsep}{1em}

% only for demonstration
\newcommand{\showwidths}{%
    \noindent%
    \rule{\colwidth{1}}{4pt}%
    \rule{\colsep}{1pt}%
    \rule{\colwidth{2}}{4pt}%
    \newline
}

% initialize columns
\setcolwidth{1}{.5\textwidth}
\setcolwidth{2}{.5\textwidth}

\begin{document}
    % for demonstration only
    \showwidths
    % the (stripped down) grid layout
    \begin{minipage}{\colwidth{1}+\colwidth{2}+\colsep}
        \parbox{\colwidth{1}}{Text in column 1, text in column 1}%
        \hspace{\colsep}%
        \parbox{\colwidth{2}}{Text in column 2, text in column 2}%
    \end{minipage}
    % for demonstration only
    \showwidths
\end{document}
```

**Additional Notes**

I do not want to change the `minipage` to a `\parbox`. I know that a `\parbox` is not changing the `\textwidth`. I am doing a lot more in my own gridlayout environment. I need to have a `minipage`.

Also I do not care if the `\setcolwidth` command uses the `\csname ... \endcsname` or the `\@namelet` commands. I just like the opportunity to learn something about `\csname ... \endcsname` and some "deeper" TeX coding.

I don't know if it is important but I am using XeTeX for compiling.

Comment: \let is not the right command to store a dimension.

Comment: Why don't you use real length to store the column width instead of using macros?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for your comment. I did not know how to use ``\setlength`` together with a non fixed name. I thought there only is ``\setlength{\length}{<value>}``. In addition I thought ``\let`` is the "more general way" so you have to use ``\let`` if you want a non fixed name. As I said I'm not really familiar with TeX programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\setlength` for setting a length, not `\let`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcolwidth}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{col#1}{\expandafter\newlength\csname col#1\endcsname}{}%
  \expandafter\setlength\csname col#1\endcsname{\dimexpr#2\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\colwidth}[1]{\csname col#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\newlength{\colsep}
\setlength{\colsep}{1em}

% only for demonstration
\newcommand{\showwidths}{%
    \noindent
    \rule{\colwidth{1}}{4pt}%
    \rule{\colsep}{1pt}%
    \rule{\colwidth{2}}{4pt}%
}

% initialize columns
\setcolwidth{1}{.5\textwidth}
\setcolwidth{2}{.5\textwidth}

\begin{document}

% for demonstration only
\showwidths

% the (stripped down) grid layout
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\colwidth{1}+\colwidth{2}+\colsep}
  \parbox{\colwidth{1}}{Text in column 1, text in column 1}%
  \hspace{\colsep}%
  \parbox{\colwidth{2}}{Text in column 2, text in column 2}%
\end{minipage}

% for demonstration only
\showwidths

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That works perfectly. Also thank you for adding the ``\@ifundefined``, I didn't even think about that.